# how to change mock object return value only for one test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, module, mocking

I have a simple suite of tests where in some cases I want to change mock a module value and in some cases not. Anyone has an idea how it to do?

this is my mock object inside mockConfig.js file

```
module.exports = {
  skillGames: {
    leftMenuWidget: {
      filterByBadge: 'exclusive',
      limit: 6,
      title: 'Exclusive games',
    },
  }
}
```

when I try mock mockConfig.js file for my test like this`

```
jest.mock('helpers/test/mockConfig', () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      skillGames: {
        leftMenuWidget: {
          limit: 6,
          title: 'Exclusive games',
        },
      },
    }));
```

I set filterByBadge value undefined for all tests, but me need that it will be undefined only for one test

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in jest that restores original implementation.

`mockFn.mockRestore()`

You can read about it [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore)